# What is the right way to help someone without wasting hours of your time trying to get all the necessary info from the OP?

Tags: discussion, questions, help-center

There are a lot of questions of this type:

```
SomeFunction(foo, out boo)
{
    someNotDeclaredVariable = foo;
    boo = NotDeclaredFunction(foo);
    for each (var something in someCollection)
    {
         Debug.Log(something + foo); // error here...
    }
    // more code 
}
```

I can see right away a very high probability of this question becoming a never ending story...

- What is the right course to take to help those without wasting hours of my time requesting more and more details from the OP? I know I can just *skip helping, skip this question* but if everyone does that then the amount of unsolved questions will grow and grow... I am not saying that we need to help every single person that asks a question - I am only mentioning this because the number of those questions is high.
- Is leaving a comment asking for more details and moving on enough? What kind of comment can I leave?
- How can I identify what is going to become a chameleon question before engaging in it?
- Is asking what seems easy to solve a sneaky way poor questions owners trick us into engaging and helping?

If we could get some good answers here it would be worth making an authoritative reference in the help centre where we redirect people who ask those *demanding* questions...

Comment: IMHO the right thing to do is to ignore it. There's plenty of questions being posted on this site so there's no need to waste hours on vampires. VTC.

Comment: If you VTC and/or downvote chances are the question won't stay around for long.

Comment: There's a close-reason specifically aimed at those cases saying that questions should contain the code needed to reproduce. It's the responsibility of the OP to fix their question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vote to Close --> Off-topic --> Minimum Complete Verifiable Example

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must **include the desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. (**emphasis mine**)

The example you posted, though common, sometimes includes an exact error message and the desired behavior.  But it is often not "the shortest code necessary to reproduce it" because either code is missing (as in your example) or code could be omitted (as in many other examples).

As you know, closed questions are "temporarily put on hold".  Emphasize that last part to the new users and a few will realize that they could do some more work and fix it, spending their hours productively, not spending your hours unproductively...

If you get tempted to answer [one of these non-MCVE debugging questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879437/why-does-my-code-using-piping-hang) be aware that a good answer will have to cover a lot more territory to hit all the bad spots. It will take more time now than a MCVE would and it will help fewer people in the future than a MCVE would.  You'll realize afterward that "too broad" might have applied to the original post as well.  And, if you are unlucky, either the OP or some viewer in the peanut gallery with an incomplete understanding of all the issues will add their critiques, making it sometimes seem like wasted hours.